# Arduino power input

Tags: arduino, voltage

Arduino power input, what pin can you use for 12V DC to supply my Arduino? What's voltage limit can the Arduino can handle?

Comment: why are you not saying which arduino you have?

Comment: arduino mega, arduino due, arduino nano, ...

Comment: The requirements for different Arduino boards is different. The Due and Uno for instance, have a DC jack that can handle a range of input voltages because they have a regulator on the board. The Arduino Micro, Nano, Fio, etc, dont have the same input range and don't have DC jack on the boards. You have to specify which board to know the possible input voltages.

Comment: My bad... The nano does have a regulator. I was thinking of the Pro Mini.

Comment: Why don't you look them up on the Arduino site? https://store.arduino.cc/ has all the specs for all the boards you have.

Comment: @JohnCalvin You need to specify the exact board and preferably also the part number of the regulator used by that board.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can use VIN and GND pin, also I think 12 V will decrease Arduino lifetime, I suggest to use between 6-9 V, and I use 7 V for my Arduino, also Arduino voltage range supported is 6-20 V and recommended voltage is 6-12 V

Comment: Accepted as this may be, it is also incorrect.

Comment: @ocrdu it's very correct

Comment: @Meow is absolutely true

Answer (score 6):

There is a linear regulator such as LM1117 on the Arduino (and clone) boards you mention. The MCU chip itself does not draw much current, but if you draw current from the GPIO pins or connect something that draws a lot of current to the 5V pin the regulator will get very hot if the input voltage is too high.

So, while you can use 12V (and the LM1117 can withstand a bit more) it's better to keep the input voltage in the 7-9V range in many cases. The LM1117 drops out at a bit over 1V worst case, so 6.5 is about the minimum you should use. The official page (for the Nano) is not self-consistent with one page showing 6-20V and the Tech Specs showing a more sensible 7-12V.